# List of 3 unique triplets from a group of 9 where every row is unique as well.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

Say we have 9 people. Every week, they will form into groups of 3. The condition is that the triplet that is formed must never have been seen together before. So let's say for week 1, we have: ABC, DEF, GHI. That means in the subsequent weeks, ABC cannot appear again. But ABD is fine. And the table goes on until all triplets have been exhausted.

I have a solution but it was done by brute force. I was wondering if this has anything to do with Steiner Systems, specifically S(3,3,9) if I am not mistaken. I have read that when t=k, the Steiner System is trivial. Since I am not a mathematician, can someone explain whether the Steiner System is relevant to the above scenario? Feel free to point me towards something else that is more relevant.

Comment: I would have thought to exhaust all triplets in a Steiner system you would have $S(3,3,84)$ and this is trivial because you just list all ${9 \choose 3}=84$ possible triplets.  But it does not in itself deal with your three triplets per week ambition (which I would have thought was $28$ weeks).

Comment: The 84 triplets can easily be constructed. But each person can only appear in one triplet every week. So this restriction makes it harder.

Comment: Nice question. Even with the restriction I suspect the answer will be $28$ weeks.

Comment: The fact that $28$ weeks are possible is a special case of [Baranyai's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baranyai%27s_theorem).

Comment: You are not just looking for a Steiner system, you are looking for a [_resolution_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design#Resolvable_2-designs) of a Steiner system. A resolution is a way to group the blocks into _parallel classes_, where the blocks in each parallel classes are disjoint and cover all of the underlying points.

Comment: Wow. That's some interesting mathematics for me to check out. I have looked up Kirkman's schoolgirl problem but thought this was closer to Sylvester's variant. The solution for 9 schoolgirls in triplets is rather similar to what I am looking for. Look under "9 schoolgirls and extensions" in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more general version of your question. Consider a set $S$ of $n$ elements. Assume that $n$ be a multiple of $k$. Consider the partitions of $S$ into $n/k$ subsets of size $k$. Can I find a collection $\mathcal{P}$ of such partitions such that every size-$k$ subset of $S$ appears in exactly one partition in $\mathcal{P}$?

The fact that the answer is yes is a result known as [Baranyai's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baranyai%27s_theorem). The formulation on Wikipedia has jargon like 'complete hypergraphs' but don't let that deter you, it's just another way of formulating the same thing.

Baranyai's theorem has a known constructive proof. There is a StackOverflow post by David Eisenstat [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25902878) which explains the construction and has a Python code snippet for algorithmically producing a collection of such partitions.

I ran the code myself for $n = 9$ and $k = 3$, and it returns the following list of $84$ triples that can be assembled into $28$ weeks. (Note that the script uses 0 through 8 instead of A through I.)

[image: Python output]

As far as I can tell, the question doesn't really have anything to do with Steiner systems, but there are very similar questions that do (some of which apparently are still open). Take a look at the [Kirkman schoolgirl problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem) as an example.